# Where is my question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Yesterday I asked a question at programmers.stackexchange.com about RESTful (or not really RESTful) APIs. In my opinion it was quite a good question and I spend some time editing it. Of course, no one has to agree with me.
Now, I cannot find any trace of it. It completely disappeared. Are questions being silently deleted?

Comment: did you check your [deleted recent questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/165773)? http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/167529

Comment: ...URL in prior comments refers page that lists deleted questions at meta; for main site it would be http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/167529

Comment: @gnat: "No deleted recent questions" - under both URLs.

Comment: the only restful question I could find for yesterday is [this one](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/275989/restful-interface) (I could probably miss something). You can try to check (including deleted questions) at your other Stack Exchange accounts - I recall seeing few times people missed the site where they are posting

Comment: @gnat I've checked all my Stack Exchange accounts and found nothing.

Comment: Hm, I don't see any deleted posts (questions or answers) in your profile. Which means that either you never submitted the question, or something went horribly wrong while you were submitting it. In any case, I'm afraid there isn't much we can do. Would it be possible to re-post it?

Comment: I have already done it (re-posted a similar question).